# RAM compatibility for notebook

Tags: memory, compatibility

I'd like to by the following laptop:

```
Notebook 15.6" HP G4 200
Intel Core i5-5200U 2,2GHz
RAM 4GB - DDR3L-SDRAM - 1600 MHz - CL: Unknown, sorry
HDD 500GB
```

I'd like to totally replace the RAM to avoid incompatibility, I thought to take this one:
[Link to shop](http://www.e-key.it/prod-ram-ddr3-so-dimm-kingston-technology-impact-pc3-12000-1600mhz-8gb-55874.htm)

```
RAM DDR3 SO-DIMM Kingston Technology Impact
PC3-12000 
1600MHz
8GB (2x4GB)
CL9
1.35V
```

But the assistance guy of the online shop told me that them aren't compatible so he told to buy these other (and spend a little more)
[Link to shop](http://www.e-key.it/prod-ram-ddr3-so-dimm-ddr3-kingston-technology-impact-pc3-12000-1600mhz-55872.htm)

```
DDR3 SO-DIMM DDR3 Kingston Technology Impact
PC3-12000
1600MHz
4GB (1x4GB)
CL9
1.35V
```

Now am I crazy and the first one is really incompatible or the guy was wise?

Comment: I doubt it's incompatible, but it's worth knowing if the stock RAM is 1x4GB or 2x2GB

Comment: You have to determine the maximum amount of memory if it's 8GB then it's unlikely the 4GB won't work

Comment: @Jonno It's 1X4GB because he told me to take 1 additional 4GB ram

Comment: @Ramhound I check right now, it has 2 slot SO-DIMM and 1 4GB installed, here is the link to the shop: http://www.e-key.it/prod-notebook-156-led-hp-g4-intel-core-i5-5200u-22ghz-ram-4gb-hdd-500gb-91174.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop you mention has a maximum RAM limit of **8GB** - [source 1](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02974953) - [source 2](http://shop.datacom.bg/eCom/product_info.php/en/laptops-m9s89ea-hp-250-g4-intelr-coretm-i5-5200u-p-36926)

Assuming your specifications are correct and currently it has 1x4GB RAM fitted, your best choice is another 1x4GB stick. This will give you the maximum supported RAM, without removing the current stick, as well as enabling Dual Channel mode if supported.

As such, go for the second option, as the first option is just 2x4GB sticks and you'll need to remove the one currently in there to fit them anyway.

Comment: I wanted to buy a new 2x4 kit to ensure compatibility because I don't know the exact brand and CL of the 1st ram (the already installed). Do you think that I won't have compatibility problems buying only 1 4GB ram (as suggested)?

Comment: @Timmy DDR3 is widely very compatible. If the two sticks were different speeds, usually the faster of the two will downclock to match the other. I doubt you'll have any problems.

Comment: @Timmy - If you can't provide us specifics on the current memory there is no way we can compare your current memory to the memory you wish to purchase.  We can only comment on the facts we can confirm.  Both kits are identical, only difference between the two, is one is a 2 module kit.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but the site I send you gives me only those information, so I'll buy 1 of that ram and I'll hope it will work :) Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically both "kits" have the same rating. I guess your laptop only has 2 RAM-slots. Since there is 1 slot already inhabitet by the original 4GB module, it would make sense to buy just 1 another 4GB stick.